# App to handle syncing custom calendar to multiple popular calendar brands (ie Outlook, ical/ics, Google, etc)

Tags: file-synchronization, calendar, synchronization

I have a custom database of calendar events, from which I can easily create an ical (or ics or other format) calendar file. My website customers are not particularly tech-savy so I'd like to implement a "one click" solution for them to sync my calendar events to their calendar app of choice. My question is how to do this. For example, I've seen it done this way, which is simply an `<a href>` link to the (rss or ical or json) file on the domain:
[image: This is how Michigan State Univ does it]  In this implementation the user has to click on the type of sync, or download, they need. **I'm looking for javascript library, or jquery example, or 3rd party tool or app that will handle the formatting of the file(s) and the sync to their Mozilla, Google and Outlook calendars?** I would guess this is functionality often implemented but I can't find any tool or examples to handle sync'ing to multiple formats/brands of calendars. I haven't found that many good examples out there in the wild.

If I have to I'll create separate instructions and file formats for each of the calendar types but I fear the more steps a user has to go through to sync their calendar the less likely they will be to use it.

Props to Michigan State Univ for the calendar sync example image.